# Unable to save a ZIP file with requests

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, urllib3, peach

I’m currently trying to check this website for it’s current list of patches and select the newest zip file back and download it. Manually, the zip file automatically pops up after I accept EULA, but in the background it redirects elsewhere (somewhere beyond the scope of network tools/Wireshark etc.)

I’ve been using the request commands to pull the zip, but instead it returns the html of the page that it redirects to (not of the zip itself).

Thus it seems I can accept the EULA, and then it redirects somewhere. But when I create that zip, based off of that the content inside is all wrong.

Is it possible to still save that zip (with requests?) If not, what are the alternatives?

Edit: Maybe an add on, or maybe the real issue. How can I tell if I’m still logged in to a site? I previously used the request session, and posted my login details then checked if it went through. But now I’m starting to feel like it’s not logging me in because the same html I received from the EULA get command is recurring everywhere else. My return looks something like the src code behind [LOG IN, also shows when I’m looking at the response from the EULA](https://portal.peachfuzzer.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F)

Instead of the actual list

Comment: If the EULA pops up so it's a JavaScript script that make a request to the server in order to download the file. In which i guess it uses some special headers or it make a request to a specific URL. So, try to inspect the requests in your browser to bypass/fulfill the EULA confirmation.

Comment: I can fulfill the EULA confirmation, but I can’t access the link directly associated to the zip if there is one. The page where the zip download popup appears isn’t really associated to it. Like usually on most download places there’s a link that says “click here if download doesn’t start” or something similar but that’s not the case here

Comment: can you share the link ?

Comment: Not sure if you’ll be able to access without a license, but portal.peachfuzzer.com (downloads tab)

Comment: well i can't access ... Sorry i can't help you more in this case.